# Extract polygons from shapefile using Geotools

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I have a shape file (Sample.shp) along with two other files (Sample.shx and Sample.dbf), which has geometry (polygons) defined for 15 pincodes of Bombay.

I am able to view the .shp file using the Quickstart tutorial.

```
    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

    // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Now display the map
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
```

Now I want to convert the geometry of these 15 pincodes to 15 Geometry/Polygon objects so that I can use Geometry.contains() to find if a point falls in a particular Geometry/Polygon.

I tried:

```
ShapefileReader r = new ShapefileReader(new ShpFiles(file),true,false,geometryFactory);
System.out.println(r.getCount(0)); >> returns 51
System.out.println(r.hasNext()); >> returns false
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't need to extract the geometries your self - just create a filter and iterate through the filtered collection. In your case there will probably be only one feature returned.

```
Filter pointInPolygon = CQL.toFilter("CONTAINS(the_geom, POINT(1 2))");
SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures(filter);

    SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = features.features();
    try {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
            Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
           /*... do something here */
        }
    } finally {
        iterator.close(); // IMPORTANT
    }
```

For a full discussion of querying datastores see the [Query Lab](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looks like this should  work for me. I tried featureSource.getFeatures().size() >> 15 (this is correct as I have 15 polygons). But when I do Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("CONTAINS(THE_GEOM, POINT(72.83 18.94))"); and then featureSource.getFeatures(filter) >> NULL (This should return size of 1 as this point lies in one of the polygons). Google coordinates for this are (18.94,72.83) Any suggestions?

Comment: try POINT(72.83 18.94) - lat/lon and x/y are not intuitive

Comment: hey thanks for the solution.. I just changed "THE_GEOM" to "the_geom" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used the above solution and tried a few combinations. Just changed "THE_GEOM" to lower case and POINT is in order (Lon Lat)

```
Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("CONTAINS(the_geom, POINT(72.82916 18.942883))");
SimpleFeatureCollection collection=featureSource.getFeatures(filter);
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = collection.features();

        try {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
                .....
            }
        } finally {
            iterator.close(); // IMPORTANT
        }
```

Comment: It'd be good to accept iant's answer since your changes are very minor.

Comment: yes I agree. But I would like to direct the users to the exact solution and I can just select one right answer. Hope you understand

Comment: Ok. I've edited iant's answer to resolve the case sensitivity issue.